# get arguments passed to a function as a hash

Tags: perl

I am wondering if it is possible to get the passed arguments to a function as a hash.

I tried this way:

```
my %hash = @_;
```

which worked in the scence that I got an array, however the keys were the odd variable values and the values were the even variable values.

I want the keys to be the names of the variables, so if I for example call

```
foo($bar, %example);
```

The hash will have a key bar with value the value of  $bar

(and same goes for %example).

Is this possible or must I create the hash before calling the function?

Comment: Hashes are *in a sense* arrays where the odd elements are keys and the even ones are their values. `@_` is an array (as the `@` is telling you), and when you assign it to a hash variable what happens is just what you describe. You could *either* call the sub as `foo( key => 'value', ... )` *or* use `@_` like `my ( $scalar, %hash ) = @_` (to match your example).

Comment: `foo($bar, %example);` will always result in odd number of elements. What makes you think different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To some extent, it can be done with PadWalker. That's not something you want to do outside of development tools.

But the concept makes no sense. It means you'd have to do

```
my $bar = 4;
foo($bar, %example);
```

instead of

```
foo(4, %example);
```

Stick with

```
foo(bar => $bar, %example);
```

or

```
foo(bar => $bar, example => \%example);
```

(depending on what you want).